# How to correct warning CS1707?

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class BreakingChange
    {
        delegate void SampleDelegate(string x);

        public void CandidateAction(string x)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Snippet.CandidateAction");
        }

        public class Derived : BreakingChange
        {
            public void CandidateAction(object o)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Derived.CandidateAction");
            }
        }

        static void Main()
        {
            Derived x = new Derived();
            SampleDelegate factory = new SampleDelegate(x.CandidateAction);
            factory("test");
        }
    }
}
```

> \Program.cs(32,38): warning CS1707: Delegate 'ConsoleApplication1.BreakingChange.SampleDelegate' bound to 'ConsoleApplication1.BreakingChange.Derived.CandidateAction(object)' instead of 'ConsoleApplication1.BreakingChange.CandidateAction(string)' because of new language rules
>   \Program.cs(23,25): (Related location)
>   \Program.cs(16,21): (Related location)

**Question:** 
I know what causes this warning and know the reason behind it. However, I don't know what the
best way to fix it?

1> Redefine the function (i.e.) change the function signature

2> Can we explicitly call BreakingChange.CandidateAction in the following line?

```
SampleDelegate factory = new SampleDelegate(x.CandidateAction);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, there are multiple ways to "fix" this, depending on what you want to, and can, do.

Personally I would add another overload to Derived that took a string, since you're going to have the same issue with non-delegate calls as well.

```
public class Derived : BreakingChange
{
    public new void CandidateAction(string x)
    {
        base.CandidateAction(x);
    }

    public void CandidateAction(object o)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Derived.CandidateAction");
    }
}
```

Or, since you know you want the base class method, you can cast the reference `x`:

```
new SampleDelegate(((BreakingChange)x).CandidateAction)
```

Comment: I wanted to make the answer more complete by referencing the exact part of the C# specification that outlines why the warning appear in the first place, and I think it is covered in section 7.3 (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691331(VS.71).aspx), but I'm not grokking it good enough to be able to see if it really does. The OP says he knows the reason, but for future visitors it would be nice to have the definite reason behind this available.

Comment: Agh, that was a really old link, let me check the updated one, perhaps that is clearer.

Comment: Casting x to the base type makes sense if 'BreakingChange::CandidateAction' is the desired delegate.  If Derived::CandidateAction is the correct delegate then I can't think of a good way to avoid the warning.  In that case the only option would seem to be to use [#pragma warning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/441722ys.aspx) to temporarily disable CS1707

Comment: @Frank I agree, but it didn't sound like the OP wanted to just get rid of the warning though. I try to avoid the specific situation specifically due to the method resolution here so it's not something I have done a lot. Usually if I have to resort to disabling a warning, that's a pretty strong signal that I'm doing something wrong. Still, could be, and yes, definitely squelch the compiler with a pragma if that is all that can be done.

Comment: @Lasse I see what you are saying, and I totally agree about supressing warnings usually being a sign that something is wrong.  However, we can't assume that BreakingChange::CandidateAction is the correct delegate.  Even if it is the correct delegate in this specific case, in the general case Derived::CandidateAction has just as much right to be the 'correct' delegate.  When it is, there doesn't seem to be a better answer than suppressing the warning (much as I would like there to be a better answer).

Comment: @Frank I agree, and I guess that just goes back to the reason for why the warning is there in the first place.

Comment: @Lasse, Simply beautiful answer! -- Many Thanks:)